How to evenly divide a table in a coordinate system?
I am trying to divide a table so that there are 4 chairs evenly spaced out across one side.

Table in a x,y coordinate system

It should look something like this. 

The tables center is located at X-axis position 0. The table is `123` units across, it is then scaled by `4.625`. The red line in the image is the X coordinate. What I tried to do is get the X position for the leftmost edge of the table, then try to figure out a way to increment it by a amount that would equally distribute the chairs along the X-Axis. 

This is what I have so far: 
let tableCenterCoordinateX = 0;

let leftmostTableEdge = tableCenterCoordinateX  -  ( (123*4.625) / 2);

let numberOfDivisions = ( (123*4.625)/ 8 );

let step = 0;

let chairPosition = leftmostTableEdge + (numberOfDivisions*step); //where the chair will be placed along the X-Axis


It appears to work if I alternate the "step" variable, basically if I place a chair with the step = 1, then step = 3, step = 5, step = 7. This appears to evenly distribute the chairs, but I am not exactly sure why, is there a better way to do this? I understanding this is not exactly math related, but my problem is math specific.

You should say in your title that your table has an elliptical shape, unless you consider more general shapes. Anyway, you need the equations of these shapes for a mathematical treatment.

@user 184669 The circumference is in terms of elliptic integrals and the ellipse eccentricity.

@Narasimham I do not have a equation. I have the width of the table which is 123*4.625, and the X-Axis position of the center of the table which is 0. I am just trying to divide it evenly along the X-Axis so that I know where to place the 4 chairs so that they are evenly spaced along the X-axis. Is there a way to do this without a equation?

@JeanMarie I do not have a equation. I have the width of the table which is 123*4.625, and the X-Axis position of the center of the table which is 0. Is there anyway to evenly divide it along the X-Axis so that the 4 chairs are evenly spaced out along the X-Axis without having a equation?

You have chosen to place the chairs at $1,3,5,7$, where $0$ is the left edge of the table and $8$ is the right edge of the table. This spaces them out evenly, and also makes the outer margin between the chair and the table edge half the size. This is quite a pleasing, but maybe you want the flexibility to change those margins. You could do something like this:
let numberOfChairs = 4;
let margin = 0.5;  // Change this value to get other margin sizes
let tableCenterCoordinateX = 0;
let tableWidth = 123*4.625;
let leftmostTableEdge = tableCenterCoordinateX  -  tableWidth/2;
let stepSize = tableWidth / (2*margin + numberOfChairs - 1);

let chairXPosition = leftmostTableEdge + margin*stepSize;  // first chair position
for chair = 1 to numberOfChairs
   // draw chair at chairXPosition here
   chairXPosition = chairXPosition + stepSize;  // calculate next chair position


If I understood right, there are 5 intervals on major axis and 4 equidistant chair stations spaced $2a/5$ apart. So from the standard equation of ellipse
$$ \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} =1 $$
find the four $y ~$s for $x= \pm \dfrac{a}{5},~x=\pm \dfrac{3a}{5},$ if you want them. Same spacing left on both sides.


The OP seems to have made the two outer intervals half-sized, so the interval is divided into 8 equal parts, with the chairs at 1/8, 3/8, 5/8, 6/8. That way the chairs are equally spaced 1/4 apart, with the two end intervals each being 1/8.

Yes, we can do so now, its  now more clear what OP wanted.
